# Swift 3 - Rearrange and persist the cells in tableview

Tags: uitableview, core-data, swift3, drag-and-drop

I have a tableview which I can add items to it and it will save to core data, I can also delete these items and it all works fine

However now I want to rearrange the cells and persist the data as well
At the moment I can select the barbutton Edit and it will allow me to rearrange the cells but the moment i leave the viewcontroller it will reset to how it was

Can someone please help me?

```
class CustomWorkoutViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var newMusclesTableView: UITableView!

var workout:Workout?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    newMusclesTableView.delegate = self

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "muscleListTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    newMusclesTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "workCell")

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.newMusclesTableView.reloadData()
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "addMuscles"{
        guard let destination = segue.destination as? AddMusclesViewController else {
            return
        }
        destination.workout = workout

    }

    else if segue.identifier == "addLogs"{
        guard let destination = segue.destination as? WorkoutViewController,
            let selectedRow = self.newMusclesTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else {
                return
        }
        destination.muscleLog = workout?.muscleList?[selectedRow]
    }


}

func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let point = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: newMusclesTableView as UIView)
    let indexPath: IndexPath! = newMusclesTableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)

    let vc = viewMusclesViewController()
    let viewTitle = workout?.muscleList?[indexPath.row]

    vc.customInit(title: (viewTitle?.name)!)
    vc.titleStr = viewTitle?.name
    vc.gifStr = viewTitle?.muscleImage
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}

@IBAction func editAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    self.newMusclesTableView.isEditing = !self.newMusclesTableView.isEditing
    sender.title = (self.newMusclesTableView.isEditing) ? "Done" : "Edit"

}


func deleteMuscle(at indexPath: IndexPath){
    guard let muscles = workout?.muscleList?[indexPath.row],
        let managedContext = muscles.managedObjectContext else{
            return
    }
    managedContext.delete(muscles)

    do{
        try managedContext.save()

        newMusclesTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }catch{
        print("Could not save")
        newMusclesTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

And this is my tableview extension

```
extension CustomWorkoutViewController: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return workout?.muscleList?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = newMusclesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "muscleCell", for: indexPath) as? muscleListTableViewCell

    cell?.cellView.layer.cornerRadius = (cell?.cellView.frame.height)! / 2


    if let muscles = workout?.muscleList?[indexPath.row]{
        cell?.muscleTitle?.text = muscles.name
        cell?.myBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }


    return cell!
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete{
        deleteMuscle(at: indexPath)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

//How to persist data here?

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my own question
I will post it here for future if anyone needed help

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let muscle = workout?.muscleList?[sourceIndexPath.row]
    workout?.removeFromRawMuscles(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    workout?.insertIntoRawMuscles(muscle!, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

    do{
        try muscle?.managedObjectContext?.save()


    }catch{
        print("Rows could not be saved")
    }
}
```

Comment: That's literally what I said. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code decides which item to display for a row with this code:

```
if let muscles = workout?.muscleList?[indexPath.row]
```

The row order is going to be determined by the order in `muscleList`. The table view can rearrange cells when you use its edit mode, but it can't save that new order because it doesn't know how to change the order of `muscleList`. Your implementation of `tableView(_:moveRowAt:to:)` needs to change the order based on the table view update.

If `muscleList` is an ordered relationship, change the order. If it's not an ordered relationship then you'll need to add a property that you can use to sort the relationship-- even something as simple as a `sortOrder` property would do.